# Auto Reboot EC2 Micro

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, amazon-ec2, service, reboot

Hi I'm cheap and use the EC2 Micro Instance with 1 ip to run my programs which need to be nearly 24/7. I usually experience very bad performance after 2 hours of running and was wondering if there was some way to automatically reboot every 2 hours. I really only need to run to 2 scripts after the server comes back on. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I usually experience very bad performance after 2 hours of running and was wondering if there was some way to automatically reboot every 2 hours.

I think the first thing that you should consider is why does the ec2 machine 'slows down' after 2hours. I have been using the micro instances for quite some time and I never experience poor performance. Use tools like `top` and `htop` to scan for memory-hungry programs and make sure that every process is executing within its domains.

Secondly, if you want to schedule a re-boot of the machine, I would recommend using cron jobs for it. If you absolutely must scheule your machine on every 2hours or so, simply write up cron job inside the file `/etc/crontab` and refer to this [document](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) for specifying time

Comment: Thanks a lot I learned the many features of cron and ended up using crontab to run a lot of my shell scripts.

Comment: Thats great. Crontab is an excellent utility if *Unix machines

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule reboot for a specific time

```
shutdown -r 20:00
```

will reboot the system at 8PM. You could write something into your .profile to cause the machine to reboot itself two hours after booting up, or run a cron job to do it.

Remember shutdown requires root access, you might need sudo shutdown depending on how you are logged on.